# Are JavaScript forms enough for spam block

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, spam

I have a question.

Spam bots can't/don't use JavaScript.  If I create form which works only with JavaScript enabled, is it enough to block spam bots?

I am talking about forms, that load fields via jQuery-ajax.  These fields are required to send the form.  Is it enough or am I only dreaming and should use some methods like non-visible input forms?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your reasoning that spam bots don't, can't use JavaScript is incorrect. Most spam bots won't execute JS, but there are a lot than actually can and will execute JS.

There are a few possible techniques that you could employ:

- Require users to log in. Always works, but it might not be what you want
- Captchas: the most effective (provided you use good captcha's), but unfortunately also the most annoying from the user's point of view
- Honeypot: Include one field with a regular name (and make it hidden with CSS for example). When you receive the form values on the server, if the field is not empty, it's a spam request and you deny it. A normal user wouldn't fill it in, so when it's filled in, it's probably a spam bot just filling in everything.

Comment: I like this answer, but please, as a user I beg you: choose honeypot and moderation over captchas.

Comment: Agreed, that's why I mentioned it. Recently you also see less usage of captchas than a few years ago, so I think there's a bit of a concensus there

Comment: Thank You. I know a lot of methods to block spam. Usualy I use time trap + honeypot. Sometimes logic riddle. I do not use captcha becouse it is totaly unaccessible for screenreaders and also for low vision people.  I was curious if js is enought, becouse i read a lot of articles about spam bots, and most of it tells that bots can not use js. Thank You, Your answer is right for me and situation is clear now.